# Oracle, Execute a string as query and return the result set

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to create a string query in oracle and then execute it. I know I can do that using execute immediate, however I do not get a result set back. As far as I understand I could use a cursor to retrieve the rows one by one but still this doesn't seem to do the job (I suppose cursors are just references not result sets, or probably my knowledge is quite limited but anyway). To make it more clear, I want to execute this string query through BIRT Reporting Tool, which always gives me an error message "SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object".

The concept is as follows:

**1.** I have a **tableA** with some names.For example Nike, Adidas...I do not know which those tables are.(has to be dynamic)

**2.** For each table there are other tables such as Nike.**stores**, Adidas.**stores**.
The bad thing is that the high level table has no connection with the low level ones. For example Nike table has no relation with Nike.**stores** table (Unfortunately this is the way the database was designed..).

**3.** So in MS SQL I create a string like:

```
SELECT @SqlStr = @SqlStr + N'SELECT * FROM ' + names + N'.stores 
UNION ALL '  FROM **tableA** Group by names
```

which would actually be executed like:

```
Select * from Nike.stores UNION ALL Select * from Adidas.stores ...
```

This works fine since it returns a result set.

My question is how is it possible to do it in oracle??By the way I am trying not to use procedures or functions as it is one of the initial requirements. However, I suppose this could be the only way.

Comment: How do actually make the query call from BIRT? If you can't build up the query on the toool command, can you execute an anonymous PL/SQL block from the call, and can it use bind variables?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what are the tables to fetch from, then unfortunately you are a victim of a bad design. In order to do it in SQL, you must know the table names, i.e. the it must be static and cannot be dynamic.

So, you are left with one option, **dynamic SQL**. And you could only do it in `PL/SQL` using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

**UPDATE** To return a refcursor, use OPEN FOR with the dynamic SQL.

Just an example,

```
SQL> variable cur refcursor
SQL> DECLARE
  2    tab_name VARCHAR2(10);
  3    str_sql  VARCHAR2(200);
  4  BEGIN
  5    tab_name :='EMP';
  6    str_sql  :='SELECT empno, ename FROM '||tab_name;
  7    OPEN :cur FOR str_sql;
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print cur

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Lalit. Thanks for the reply. I already know I have to use dynamic SQL. My question was how am I supposed to return a result set when executing a string query since EXECUTE IMMEDIATE doesn't do that.

Comment: Ok, understood your problem. You need to form the dynamic string, and then open it as a ref cursor. See my update.